# XML - convert columns to individual rows?

Tags: xml, xslt, transpose

I'm pretty new to XML/XSLT, so apologies if this is simple. I'm trying to convert an XML file containing columns indicating payments to employees, so that each **payment** is on a separate row, along with the employee info, and the payment type for that column.

i.e. from this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report>
<Row><col1>ID</col1><col2>NAME</col2><col3>SALARY</col3><col4>BONUS</col4><col5>SICK PAY</col5><col6>CHRISTMAS PAY</col6></Row>
<Row><col1>1001</col1><col2>Joe Bloggs</col2><col3>1500.00</col3><col4>150.00</col4><col5>50.00</col5><col6>0.00</col6></Row>
<Row><col1>1005</col1><col2>Jane Smith</col2><col3>2000.00</col3><col4>250.00</col4><col5>25.00</col5><col6>15.00</col6></Row>
</Report>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report>
<Row><ID>1001</ID><NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME><PAYTYPE>SALARY</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>1500.00</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1001</ID><NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME><PAYTYPE>BONUS</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>150.00</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1001</ID><NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME><PAYTYPE>SICKPAY</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>50.00</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1001</ID><NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME><PAYTYPE>CHRISTMASPAY</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>0</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1005</ID><NAME>Jane Smith</NAME><PAYTYPE>SALARY</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>2000.00</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1005</ID><NAME>Jane Smith</NAME><PAYTYPE>BONUS</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>250.00</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1005</ID><NAME>Jane Smith</NAME><PAYTYPE>SICKPAY</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>25.00</AMOUNT></Row>
<Row><ID>1005</ID><NAME>Jane Smith</NAME><PAYTYPE>CHRISTMASPAY</PAYTYPE><AMOUNT>15.00</AMOUNT></Row>
</Report>
```

The challenge is that it needs to be dynamic to accommodate more columns if they're added (with other payments). Is this even possible?

Honestly, I don't know where to start. I've tried cobbling together some XSLT based on various google searches to try and output even one column, e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="column-name" match="Row[1]/Item" use="count(preceding-sibling::Item)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Report/Row[position() > 1]">
            <Row>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <Column name="{key('column-name', count(preceding-sibling::Item))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Column>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But no joy at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Many thanks :)
AJ

Comment: I don't see any `Item` elements in your input sample so why does the XSLT code try to select `Row[1]/Item`?

Comment: Apologies, I was trying various different iterations of the sample XML, so that XSLT was when the nodes were all called 'item' instead of 'col1', 'col2,' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tries to use your key but obviously not on non-existing `Item` but on any element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="column-name" match="Row[1]/*" use="count(preceding-sibling::*)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Row[position() > 1]/*[position() > 2]"/>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row/*">
    <Row>
      <xsl:element name="{../../Row[1]/*[1]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="../*[1]"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="{../../Row[1]/*[2]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="../*[2]"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <PAYTYPE>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('column-name', count(preceding-sibling::*))"/>
      </PAYTYPE>
      <AMOUNT>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </AMOUNT>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Table>
  <Row>
    <ID>1001</ID>
    <NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>SALARY</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>1500.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1001</ID>
    <NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>BONUS</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>150.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1001</ID>
    <NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>SICK PAY</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>50.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1001</ID>
    <NAME>Joe Bloggs</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>CHRISTMAS PAY</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>0.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1005</ID>
    <NAME>Jane Smith</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>SALARY</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>2000.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1005</ID>
    <NAME>Jane Smith</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>BONUS</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>250.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1005</ID>
    <NAME>Jane Smith</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>SICK PAY</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>25.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1005</ID>
    <NAME>Jane Smith</NAME>
    <PAYTYPE>CHRISTMAS PAY</PAYTYPE>
    <AMOUNT>15.00</AMOUNT>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Martin - incredible. I will dissect the code and try to learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="column-name" match="Row[1]/*" use="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1" />

<xsl:template match="/Report">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="col1" />
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="col2" />
            <xsl:for-each select="*[position() > 2]">
                <Row>
                    <ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
                    </ID>
                    <NAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
                    </NAME>
                    <PAYTYPE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="key('column-name', position() + 2)" />
                    </PAYTYPE>
                    <AMOUNT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </AMOUNT>
                </Row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming the first 2 columns are always `ID` and `NAME` that should be repeated for all result rows.

Comment: Thank you also Michael - I'll try to learn from this code too!

Comment: I hope you learn how to avoid walking up and down the  tree needlessly.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean using variables for ID and NAME so that you only need to get them once for each input Row, instead of looking them up repeatedly for each column. And of course, if their names are known, then you don't need to look those up at all.

Comment: OK, I think I get you. I'll see if I can apply that logic to my XSLT. Thanks again for your continued input.